# A question about the proof of Borsuk's lemma in Munkres' topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness

[image]

My problem is with the part where he uses the pasting lemma to conclude that $h$ is continuous.

The pasting lemma requires that both sets on which the corresponding functions are defined be either open or closed in the whole space $X$ which is $R^2$ in this case.

$A$ is a compact subspace of $R^2 - 0$ and hence is closed in it, but that doesn't guarantee it is closed in $R^2$.

$C$ and $D$ are both open in $R^2 - A$ because they are components and the space is locally path connected, but I haven't been able to prove anything about whether they are open or closed $R^2$.

It looks like a trivial detail among the main points in the proof so I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compactness of a set is a topological property: it is independent of the space in which that set is embedded. $A$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{\bf0\}$, so it is compact as a space and therefore compact as a subset of any space in which it is embedded. In particular, it is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

$C$ and $D$ are open subsets of $\Bbb R^2\setminus A$, which is open in $\Bbb R^2$, so $C$ and $D$ are open in $\Bbb R^2$. Specifically, for $C$ there is an open $U$ in $\Bbb R^2$ such that $C=U\cap(\Bbb R^2\setminus A)$, but that means that $C$ is the intersection of two open sets in $\Bbb R^2$ and hence is itself open in $\Bbb R^2$. The argument for $D$ is the same.

Comment: Still how does he use the pasting lemme? $A$ is a closed subset of $R^2$ and $C$ and $D$ are open subsets of $R^2$. The pasting lemma requires that the unions of $A$ and $D$, and of $A$ and $C$ be either open together or closed  together in $R^2$.

Comment: @Km356: $D$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$, and $A\cup C=\Bbb R^2\setminus D$, so $A\cup C$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$. Similarly, $A\cup D$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$. The pasting lemma is applied to $A\cup C$ and $A\cup D$ to get $h$. The map $k$ comes from some other result.

Comment: Oh, this is embarrassingly trivial :) thanks.

Comment: @Km356: You’re welcome. (Happens to all of us occasionally.)